# Copy and paste a chain of items on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, shortcut, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy a set of different items and then paste them in? The items have to go in separate boxes during a timed registration.
For example, Is there a way to copy the numbers:
20102
21568
20975
27965
and continuously hit control-v to paste them in subsequently (as a chain)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of without 3rd party assistance; but if you know all the strings beforehand, you could set up text replace shortcuts, so you could just type t1 t2 t3 etc & have them auto-fill.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you know any third party apps I could get to accomplish that?

Comment: the free version of https://copyless.net should do it

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know a way of doing it without an app I use `[Pastebot][1]` which is a free clipboard manager. I highly recommend it, it's "Sequential Paste Mode" does exactly what you want and it's free.

Comment: i just checked and pastebot is $10.

Comment: Then please upvote my answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @jmh They must have put a price on it. I'll have to find a free alternative.